# DB migration: Single creation script vs change sets

Tags: data-migration, liquibase

I am creating a DB schema per customer. So whenever a new customer registers I need to quickly create their schema in runtime.

## Option 1

In runtime, use Liquibase (or equivalent) to run all the changesets to generate the latest schema.

Cons:

- This is slow, there can be multiple historical change setsa which are not relevant now any more   (create table and year later drop it).
- Liquibase is used here in runtime and not just "migration time". Not sure if this is a good idea.
- Standartizing on Liquibase as a mean to create schema will force all developers to use it during development. We try to avoid loading more tools on the developers.

## Option 2

After each build we generate a temporary DB using Liquibase changesets. Then from the DB we create a clean schema creation script based on the current snapshot. Then when a new customer comes we just run the clean script, not the full change set history.

Cons:

- Next time I run liquibase it will try to run from changeset 1. A workaround might be to include in the generation script the creation of the changeset table and inserting to it the latest changeset.
- New schemas are created using one script, while old schemas go through the changeset process. In theory this might cause a different schema. However, the single script went through the changeset process as well so I can't think of exact case that will cause an error, this is a theoretical problem for now.

What do you think?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest option #1 for the consistency.

Database updates can be complex and the less chance for variation the better. That means you should have your developers create the liquibase changeSets initially to update their databases as they are implementing new features to know they are running as they expect and then know that those same steps will be ran in QA all the way through production. It is an extra tool they need to deal with, but it should be easy to integrate into their standard workflow in a way that is easy for them to use.

Similarly, I usually recommend leaving non-relevant historical changeSets in your changeLog because if you remove them you are deviating from your known-good update path. Databases are fast with most operations, especially on a system with little to no data. If you have specific changeSets that are no longer needed and are excessively expensive for one reason or another you can remove them on a case by case basis, but I would suggest doing that very rarely.

You are right that creating a database snapshot from a liquibase script should be identical to running the changeLog--as long as you include the databasechangelog table in the snapshot. However, sticking with an actual Liquibase update all the way through to production will allow you to use features such as contexts, preconditions and changelog parameters that may be helpful in your case as well.

Answer (score 0):

There are two approaches for database deployment:

1. Build once deploy many – this approach uses the same principle as the native code, compile once and copy the binaries across the environments. From database point of view this approach means that the deploy script is generated once and then executed across environments.
2. Build & Deploy on demand – this approach generates the delta script when needed in order to handle any out of process changes.

If you use the Build & Deploy on demand approach you can generate the delta script for the entire schema or work-item / changeset.